# (Ubuntu 18.04) Tensorflow with GPU Support but the gpu is only capable of compute capability 3.0

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, ubuntu-18.04

I want to set up a developement surrounding for machine learning and need tensorflow with gpu support. I have a Nvidia Cuda enabled Quadro K4200 with a Compute Capability of 3.0.

I set up the environment according to: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

> nvidia-smi
>   Fri Sep 13 12:26:47 2019
>   +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>   | NVIDIA-SMI 430.26       Driver Version: 430.26       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
>   |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
>   | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
>   | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
>   |===============================+======================+======================|
>   |   0  Quadro K4200        Off  | 00000000:04:00.0  On |                  N/A |
>   | 30%   39C    P8    17W / 110W |    243MiB /  4028MiB |      1%      Default |
>   +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1843      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            34MiB |
|    0      1877      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                           6MiB |
|    0      4057      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           103MiB |
|    0      4193      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          91MiB |
|    0      4867      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       2MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Trying if the gpu support works:
$python3

$import tensorflow as tf

$sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))

i get this as output:

> I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
>   2019-09-13 12:28:32.878677: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
>   2019-09-13 12:28:32.937236: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
>   2019-09-13 12:28:32.937662: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:197] StreamExecutor cuda device (0) is of insufficient compute capability: 3.5 required, device is 3.0
>   2019-09-13 12:28:32.937836: F tensorflow/stream_executor/lib/statusor.cc:34] Attempting to fetch value instead of handling error Internal: no supported devices found for platform CUDA
>   Aborted (core dumped)

What can i do to fix this? Would it fix the issue if i downgrade somehow to Cuda9?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that the issue is related to the somewhat old Nvidia card. You might need to compile TensorFlow by yourself: [Compiling TensorFlow with CUDA Compute Capability 3.0 Support](https://medium.com/@mccann.matt/compiling-tensorflow-with-cuda-3-0-support-42d8fe0bf3b5). There are a few other suggestions for the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651810/the-minimum-required-cuda-capability-is-3-5